# Move all others in class when mouseenter target jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation

I would like there to be an effect where the items not being hovered are pushed away from the item being hovered.

I hoped this would be effective, but it's not.

```
($(circle1).mouseenter(function(){
    var i, x = event.target; 

    $(".circle").each(function() {
        for (var i = circles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (circles[i] === x) {
                $(x).animate({
                    left: "+=3px",
                    top: "+=3px"
                }, 'slow')}
            else 
                circles[i].animate({
                left: "+=20px",
                top: "+=20px"
            }, 'slow')}

    })
})
```

Here is a codepen where the above code is commented out. An alternative functional script is included, but is only half right.

http://codepen.io/WallyNally/pen/GqbPEr

That one looks like this.

```
$(".circle").mouseenter(function(){
        var x = event.target; 

        $(".circle").each(function() {
            if (x === circle1) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: "+=3px",
                    top: "+=3px"
                }, 'slow')}
            else {          
            $(".circle").animate({
                left: "+=20px",
                top: "+=20px"
            }, 'slow')}

        })
    })
```

Comment: Once apon a time I made this pen: http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/bZzKPr It maybe related to what your trying to do.

Comment: @NilesTanner, this is not what I have in mind, but is helpful to finding a solution. Thank you!

Comment: Im glad it helped!